# Use system fonts (Mac OS) while using book template

Tags: fonts, mac

I'm new to LaTeX and all that stuff, but due to the fact, that I may be using it in the future at university, I just try to get along with it.

To test, I want to have a story in a pretty book. On the web, I found a template for doing so and actually I got pretty far. Unfortunately, I can't change the font, everything I try just results in 1. no change at all or 2. the same font everywhere.

As requested, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,german]{book}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Handwriting - Dakota}

\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

These are the error messages I get:

- `LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`
- `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape EU1/Handwriting-Dakota(0)/m/sl' undefined
  (Font) usingEU1/Handwriting-Dakota(0)/m/n' instead on input line`
- `Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
  file xetest.pdf may not be valid.`

No .pdf-file is created.

Comment: Note that it would be better to use the `Acorn` package rather than defining `\initfamily` that way as the package sets the font up with `\DeclareRobustCommand` and `DeclareTextFontCommand` which is less fragile and more in keeping with the way fonts are generally configured for LaTeX. You don't need to `\input` the font definition file in this case, either.  Also, don't say `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{pplj}`. In any case, this is going to override the earlier `\setmainfont`. In general, you are mixing different ways of setting fonts so they will compete and not do what you expect.

Comment: @Sverre: I'm providing a clear example on what I do in LaTeX and how it should look. As I said, I am a beginner an I want to learn. Saying to me that I should not use code, that I don't understand is absurd. As far as I know is one of the basic ideas of LaTeX to use templates and to adapt them to your own needs. That's what I try to do.

Comment: @cfr: Thank you very much, I don't understand everything of your answer, but I will continue my research on these things.

Comment: The point is not to tell us what you do in LaTeX by providing us with all the code you're using. You should only provide the code that's relevant to the problem you're experiencing. Please read about [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @yoshegg: Looking at your document you seem to want to learn how to change fonts, use lettrines, change the geometry, change the headers, change the sectioning, use decorative fonts, use and define colors, create special lists, use wallpapers, create a titlepage and how to adapt a pdflatex example to xelatex and more all in one go.  That's hilarious. Store the example somewhere and start with some simple examples. You can go back at it in two weeks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: All these things work and I don't need to change them (except for the font thing). But as Sverre said, I provided an MWE, and hopefully I may be able to add a possible solution to my example.

Comment: The warnings in your new example are warnings, not errors and they are quite normal. Your font doesn't have a slanted shape and so the upright shape is used instead.

Comment: I wrote a more complete answer for this but can no longer post it as the question has been closed.

Comment: Can you see the code, at least, [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27317/yosheggs-document)?

Comment: I installed the Dakota Font as ttf, which seems free for non commercial use. I get the same warning, but not the same error. So let's reopen this question and find out, why yoshegg gets an error. The font, by the way, includes german umlauts.

Answer (score 4):

‘Handwriting - Dakota’ is a typeface included in OS X in an Apple-proprietary format called a font suitcase, which dates back to the classic Mac OS.

LuaTeX and XeTeX have their own code for accessing font files, separate from the operating system, and cannot use these typefaces or any like it (like Hoefler Text) unless you buy them again from their original producers in OpenType format or another font format which TeX understands.

Comment: I don't have a mac, but imho Hoefler Text works fine with lualatex and xelatex -- the fontspec manual has various examples with this font.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know a way of using this font anyway? I don't have to use LuaTeX or XeTeX, any running alternative would be ok.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I said, the fonts *can* be used, but not in the forms they come from Apple in. Hoefler Text can also be [purchased from the foundry](http://www.typography.com/fonts/hoefler-text/overview/) in a fontspec-compatible format.

Comment: @yoshegg If you can find it in OTF or TTF format, you should be able to use the font. Google might help here, but I’m not sure how legal the various sites offering it for free are.

Comment: Ok, I assume I just have to use a different font. I have found it in this format, but only the apple one has the german umlauts that I need.

Comment: I doubt that @WillRobertson would have used a commercial font for the documentation and Hoefler has been used for years in all sorts of examples in the xetex mailing list and here on tex.sx.

Comment: @DavidP.Kendal Following this tutorial (http://macthoughts.net/20131112-373), I converted the font and got it working.

Comment: You can certainly convert them. I have Handwriting - Dakota configured to work with pdfTeX, never mind XeTeX. (It isn't installed, but it certainly worked.)

Answer (score 2):

To change your font, just change `\setmainfont` to a different font:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{FreeSerif}

\begin{document}
This is in another font than ``Handwriting -- Dakota''.
\end{document}
```

Note that your "error" messages are not errors, just warnings. They tell you your font lacks certain properties (I can't run your MWE since I have no access to your font).